# The loop is not working correctly

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written this loop below. It executes perfectly fine in the first iteration; however, in the second iteration, it returns the following error:

```
 Unable to locate element: 

    {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/header[2]/div[2]/nav/ul/li[2]/a"}`

Command duration or timeout: `120.06` seconds
```

The loop code is mentioned below:

```
    Workbook w2;
    w2 = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\Users\\pcs\\Desktop\\flightdata.xls")); //flight data destintion location will be same as source from flight data.
    Sheet s2 = w2.getSheet(0);

    for (k = 1; k < s2.getRows(); k++)
    {   
      //redeem flow
      d1.findElementByXPath("html/body/header[2]/div[2]/nav/ul/li[2]/a").click();
      d1.findElementByXPath("html/body/header[2]/div[2]/nav/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a").click();
      d1.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/section/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(s2.getCell(0, k).getContents());

      //pause for list to be populated
      try 
      {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
      }

      //Get all items in autocomplete list
      List<WebElement> items1 = d1.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/ul/li[3]/a"));

       //Look for item 
       for( i= 0; i <items1.size();i++)
       {
         if(items1.get(i).getText().contains(s2.getCell(0, k).getContents()))
         {
           items1.get(i).click();
           break; 
         }
       }  

         //calendar handling
         d1.findElementById("checkin").click();
         d1.findElementByXPath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/a/span").click();
         d1.findElementByXPath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a").click();

        //Select Number of Rooms
        d1.findElementById("roomscount").sendKeys("1");

        //Select Room type       
        d1.findElementById("roomtype").sendKeys("Single"); 

        //Occupant's Nationality    
        d1.findElementById("nationality").sendKeys("India");

        //Click search button       
        d1.findElementByXPath("html/body/section/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/div[4]/input").click();

        //after 2 min wait               
        d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

---

POST SEARCH HTML PAGE

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <body class="" ondrop="return false;" ondragstart="return false;" onunload="" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onload="noBack();">
    <header>
    <div class="logo">
    <div class="right">
    <ul class="login">
    <nav class="links">
    <ul>
    <li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Redeem sMiles</a>
    <ul>
    <li class="pointer sprite"> </li>
    <li class="flight">
    <li class="hotel">
    <a href="hotel.html?action=hotels">
    <span class="sprite"> </span>
    Hotels
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="smiles">
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <script src="/fm/travel/js/hotel.js" type="text/javascript">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/fm/styles/demo_table_jui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fm/travel/styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fm/travel/styles/ui-lightness/autocomplete.css">
    <script src="/fm/travel/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="/fm/travel/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <div id="loader" style="display: none;">
    <div id="modifySearchBlock" style="display: block;">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <footer>
    <script src="/fm/travel/js/jquery.js">
    <script src="/fm/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <script src="/fm/js/jquery.meanmenu.js">
    <script>
    <script src="/fm/js/jquery.simpleGal.js">
    <script>
    <script src="/fm/js/owl.carousel.js">
    <script>
    <div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
    <ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all " tabindex="0" style="display: none;"></ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The above code belongs to the page where I return once search is completed.

Again I need to go to the below link to do the search:

[image]

```
<li class="flight">
<li class="hotel">
<a href="hotel.html?action=hotels">
<span class="sprite"> </span>
Hotels
</a>
</li>
<li class="smiles">
</ul>
</li>
```

The above code belongs to the link which I need to click. please provide same suggestions.

Comment: your selector is **extremely** brittle.. can you share some HTML so we can give some recommendations?

Comment: sure..do you require the post-search page html or pre-search page html?

Comment: both, just include it in your answer.. most importantly, share the html elements that your xpath selects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the problem which my code was facing is that when search gets finished, I was trying trying to click the web elements with the same old xpaths. Actually, on close analysis I found that the xpaths of the same webelements on the results page got altered slightly due to which my script was not able to recognize the elements on new location.

Hence, i just changed the xpaths and problem got resolved.

Comment: I don't understand it was exactly I said by "Or check in which state you are at the end of the loop."

Answer (score 1):

First you should have a look to other selector than xpath which is unreadble and can be [dangerous](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-xpath), [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations) you will a lot a way to find elements. For example `cssSelector` is a very reliable way to find element.
Another advantage is that your code become more readable.

If I understand, the first iteration no problem, then the seconde one, this is the click on the dropdown at the top of your page that cause the crash.

A possible solution is that your page is not come back to its original state at the end of your loop. You could refresh the page at the end of the loop:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Or check in which state you are at the end of the loop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hey thanks a lot buddy..will try refreshing..thanks for reminding..! :)

Comment: it did not work for me..still loop is getting hanged after first itration